ReactTS : How to nest children in a "container component"?
I am working on creation of reusable front components in React using Typescript and I am struggling with a feature which seems to be possible in classic packages.
I would like to be able to nest children of a certain type in "container components" and retrieve each sets of children in the main component.
I tried a lot of variants in the type of children props such as:
export type DataGridChild = typeof DataGridColumns | typeof DataGridActions;

export type DataGridProps<T> = BaseProps & {
    data: T[];
    children: React.ReactElement<DataGridChild> | React.ReactElement<DataGridChild>[];
}

But then I can't find a way to retrieve each child with the right type. Also TypeScript does not throw any error if I add a DataGridColumn container component twice for instance.
In the end I would like to have a component usable with this kind of code:
<DataGrid data={persons}>
  <DataGridColumns>
    <DataGridColumn field="name" />
    <DataGridColumn field="age" />
    <DataGridColumn field="weight" />
    <DataGridColumn field="birthDate" type="date" />
  </DataGridColumns>
  <DataGridActions>
    <DataGridAction text="Action 1" onClick={(rd) => console.log("Action 1 clicked")} />
  </DataGridActions>
</DataGrid>

I can't find anything on the web. Does anybody has an idea on how to make it?
Thanks a lot :)

What you are getting when attempting to retrieve DataGridProps<T>::children is either a ReactElement of type DataGridChild or an Array of ReactElements of type DataGridChild. You shouldn’t be getting anything else.

”…TypeScript does not throw any error if I add a DataGridColumn container component twice for instance.” because you specified that in DataGridProps<T>::children. TypeScript does not do what you didn’t ask it to do.

The thing was more, the way I made it I don't get any error which is bad, so can I make it to get an error, not why don't I get an error.

Since you are using Unions, you will ultimately do that which the so called classic packages do: Union narrowing. See more at Working with Union Types. [typescriptlang.org]

Let’s break down the code. You declared a type alias called DataGridChild for the Union:
typeof DataGridColumns | typeof DataGridActions
So that anywhere a DataGridChild is used, a typeof DataGridColumns or a typeof DataGridActions is expected. Since that’s the choice, expect to perform narrowing.
Next you declared a type alias DataGridProps<T> for the anonymous type built by extending a type BaseProps and including two properties:
BaseProps & {
    data: T[];
    children: React.ReactElement<DataGridChild> | React.ReactElement<DataGridChild>[];
}

data: An array of objects of type T.
children: A Union type whose value may be any one of:React.ReactElement<DataGridChild>
Or an Array of:React.ReactElement<DataGridChild>
Again since that’s the choice, expect to perform narrowing too.


With the explanations now out of the way, you should be able to answer your questions.
For posterity however, let’s answer them together.

I can't find a way to retrieve each child with the right type.

Perform Union narrowing.

Also TypeScript does not throw any error if I add a DataGridColumn container component twice for instance.

You only defined a type alias DataGridProps<T> which I suspect you used to declare and define the prop of element DataGrid.
If you didn’t define a prop Interface for neither DataGridColumns nor DataGridActions, then their props are implicitly any. Because of this, TypeScript will not provide type checking hence no type checking errors. Define an Interface for the components to provide finer control and type safety for the components.

Union narrowing ! That's the thing I was looking for. Thanks Chukwujiobi Canon for your detailed answer :)
